# how to show records both the tables side by side

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have App table and Apphistory table i need to show app records and app history record side by side columns

```
declare @app table (Appno varchar(10),Name varchar(10),Height INT,weight INT,Createddate datetime)
insert into @app (Appno,Name,Height,weight,Createddate)values 
('app1035','tom',10,60,'2015-07-02 20:14:45.590'),
('app1036','john',8,40,'2015-07-02 20:14:45.590'),
('app1037','jim',9,36,'2015-07-02 20:14:45.590')

declare @apphistory table 
(
Appno varchar(10),
Name varchar(10),
Height INT,
weight INT,
Createddate datetime)
insert into @apphistory (Appno,Name,Height,weight,Createddate)
values('app1035','tom',10,60,'2015-07-02 20:14:45.590')
,('app1035','tom',8,45,'2015-06-02 20:14:45.590'),
('app1035','tom',6,NULL,'2015-05-02 20:14:45.590'),
('app1036','john',8,40,'2015-07-02 20:14:45.590')
,('app1036','john',8,40,'2015-06-02 20:14:45.590'),
('app1036','john',NULL,NULL,'2015-05-02 20:14:45.590')

select A.Appno, COALESCE(H.Appno,A.Appno)HAppno,
A.Name,COALESCE(H.Name,A.Name)Hname,
A.Height,COALESCE(H.Height,A.Height)Hheight,
A.weight,COALESCE(H.weight,A.weight)Hweight,
A.Createddate,COALESCE(H.Createddate,A.Createddate)Hcreateddate

FROM @app A LEFT JOIN  (select top 1 Appno,Name,Height,weight,Createddate from @apphistory ORDER BY Createddate  )H
ON  A.Appno = H.Appno
WHERE A.Appno = 'app1036'
```

but what my problem is when there is Appno in App table and not there in App history table i will show record from App table.
when there is record in both tables i need to show old record of same app no with the values from Apphistory table

out put should be like :

```
Appno   HAppno  Name    Hname   Height  Hheight weight  Hweight Createddate Hcreateddate
app1036 app1036 john    john    8   NULL    40  NULL    2015-07-02 20:14:45.590 2015-07-02 20:14:45.590
```

Comment: When you have multiple records in the history table, which one you want to get in line with Appno?

Comment: for the appno in app table i'm getting the oldest record from history table @Kaf by using order by created date

Comment: The solution to your problem is a left join, but you already have one in your code, so the question isn't clear.   Can you narrow the focus down to what it is that you don't know how to do?

Comment: if data is not there in history table i will show from app table by  using coalesce but my problem if app no is there in both tables but if the value of height and weight is null in history table it is showing value from app table because of coalesce how i can show null @TabAlleman

Comment: You could coalesce your select from the history table with the string value 'NULL', so that it would not get coalesced with the app table if there is a row that matches.   It would only get coalesced if there was no matching row in history.

Comment: can you tell me how can i achieve that if the value there in both tables show the values same if not there use coalesce but how can it be done @TabAlleman

Comment: No, sorry, I don't understand the syntax of your question in your last comment.   It is not clear to me what you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` function to extract oldest record by created date. [Fiddle sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2611e/2)

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Appno ORDER BY CreatedDate) rn
   FROM @apphistory
)
SELECT a.*, h.*
FROM @app a
        LEFT JOIN CTE h ON a.Appno = h.Appno AND h.rn = 1
```

You can use `Coalesce()` function to fill null values and order the select column list for your preference.

Comment: i'm extracting old record only by using top 1 order by created date..what about the 3 rd  record which is not there in history table but present in App table

Comment: let me clear you if i give app1037 in where condition it should show values in all coumns my problem it is working in all cases but when values is there in both tables but height or weight is null in history table it is showing value from app table because use of coalesce

Comment: If you need `null` then don't use `coalesce()`. If you don't need `null` then replace it using `coalesce()`.

Comment: i know but how i need to satisfy both the conditions through query

Comment: How come you have both conditions? need null and don't need null ? not clear about your requirement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82219/discussion-between-mohan111-and-kaf).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified code-sample of what I am suggesting:

```
SELECT a.AppNo, COALESCE(ah.Height, a.Height) AS Height 
FROM App a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT AppNo, COALESCE(Height, 'NULL') AS Height
  FROM AppHistory
) ah
  ON a.AppNo=ah.AppNo
```

I realize this leaves out a lot of the logic in your original question, I am only trying to illustrate the layered Coalesce technique I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: this code is working when nulls present in History table and records there in history table but when record is not present in history table it showing null values just execute the code for app1037

Comment: When there is no record in the history table, it will show the Height in the App table.   The only way to get NULL then would be if the value in the App table is NULL.

Comment: i have tried it is working when there is no record in history table.but it is not working when records are there in both table it's coalescing for the both values and not showing any nulls .please check once

Comment: If the AppHistory is NULL, then the result will be the string value 'NULL' instead of a real NULL.